# Beginner code involving vectors , SEIGSEV runtime error

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int ways(vector<int> & ,int);

int main()

{
    int test;                       //TEST CASE
    cin>>test;
    for(int i=0 ; i<test ; i++)

    {   
        int n,k;                        // 'n' INPUT TOTAL NUMBER OF BOXES.
                                        // EACH HAVING SOME NUMBER IN IT.
        cin>>n;
        vector<int> A;

        cout<<endl;

        for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)        // inputs numbers inside all the boxes.
        cin>>A[j];

        cout<<endl;

        cin>>k;                         // input k                                 

        int ans = ways(A,k);            // find total ways to pick BOXES.  
        cout<<endl<<ans;                // such that sum in 2 boxes equals k.
    }

return 0;
}


int ways(vector<int> &B , int k)        // function , passing vector and k .

{
    int n = B.size();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<n-1 ; i++)
        for(int j=i+1 ; j<n ; j++)

            { if((B[i]+B[j])==k)
                count++;
            }
    return count;

}
```

---

Beginner programmer here , i've been stuck on this code for long , i've explained what it's for in the comments , and am getting a runtime error! please help!

Im new to vectors , so just trying to work it out , i tried const keyword before the vector declarations and didnt get any success either , it gives some other error :(

Comment: Access out of range with `std::vector::operator[]` does not resize the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take a look at these lines:

```
vector<int> A;
....
for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)        // inputs numbers inside all the boxes.
    cin>>A[j];
```

The first line defines `A` as an ***empty*** vector of `int`. Then in the loop you try ti use indexes into the vector, which is still empty. Any indexing of an empty vector will be out of bounds, and lead to *undefined behavior*.

There are two solutions:

1. Either you need to [*push back*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) elements into the vector, like e.g.

   ```
   for(int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)        // inputs numbers inside all the boxes.
   {
       int t;
       cin >> t;
       A.push_back(t);
   }
   ```
2. *Or* you create a vector with the size set:

   ```
   vector<int> A(n);
   ```